# Integral geometric meaning of diameter

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, integral-geometry

Let $X\subset \mathbb CP^n, n>2$ be a complex smooth algebraic hypersurface.

Any hyperplane section $H\cap X$ is connected and has diameter $Diam(H\cap X)$
in the inner metric induced from the Fubini-Study on $\mathbb CP^n$.

1. Let $a:= \inf_H Diam(H\cap X)$. Is there an upper estimate on the diameter (in the inner metric) of $X$ in terms of $a$? In other words, are the diameters of hyperplane sections of hypersurfaces of large diameter also large.
2. If the answer to the first question is no, is there any known expression of $Diam(X)$ in terms of properties of $H\cap X$? What is a minimal knowledge of geometry of $H\cap X$ that allows to reconstruct the diameter?
3. Is there an upper/lower bound on $Diam(X)$ in terms of the avarage  value (over all $H$) of $Diam(H\cap X)$

Comment: $\mathrm{diam}\,X\leqslant b$, or did I miss something?

Comment: @AntonPetrunin yes, of course -- any hyperplane section is nonempty and connected (e.g. by Fulton-Hansen theorem).
To be honest, I forgot what I meant by this question, probably the _lower bound_.
The real question was the following: is the diameter of hypersurfaces in $\mathbb CP^n$ bounded by a universal constant? The answer is "no" for curves in $\mathbb CP^2$ (Bogomolov) and I was thinking what it can mean for higher dimensional situation in terms of integral geometry (apparently nothing interesting).

Comment: Why not to correct the question?

Comment: @AntonPetrunin done, also removed an obviously false claim in par. 2.
Also, an upper bound on hyperplane sections diameter doesn't  give a lower bound on the diameter of $X\subset \mathbb CP^3$ since one can always take a cone over an (arbitrary large diameter) curve of Bogomolov in $\mathbb CP^2$.